# SI kafka-Message flow based on router condition

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

Requirement: expecting to receive/process the inMessage in inMessageHandler and emailMessage in emailMessageHandler.

issue: (if the consumer group-id is different for consumer-configurations) message is flowing till the ConsumerServiceHandler's transform method in both the case but not getting it in case of the emailMessage in emailMessageHandler.(but coming for inMessage in inMessageHandler).

issue: (if the consumer group-id is same for consumer-configurations) message is flowing from the ConsumerServiceHandler's transform method to emailMessage in emailMessageHandler  but not receiving the inMessage in inMessageHandler at all(not even in the ConsumerServiceHandler's transform method).

could you please suggest what's  wrong here.How can I receive the different message on different service class for processing  based on the topic id ?

Please find the configuration below.

```
    <int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext">
    <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:producer-configuration broker-list="localhost:9092"
                   key-class-type="java.lang.String"
                   value-class-type="com.test.EmailMessageVo"
                   topic="emailMessag_topic"
                   value-encoder="emailvalueEncoder"
                   key-encoder="kafkaSerializer"
                   compression-type="none"/>
        <int-kafka:producer-configuration broker-list="localhost:9092"
           key-class-type="java.lang.String"
               value-class-type="com.test.InMessageVo"
                   topic="inMessage_topic"
           value-encoder="invalueEncoder"
                   key-encoder="kafkaSerializer"
                   compression-type="none"/>
    </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
</int-kafka:producer-context>



 <bean id="invalueEncoder" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaEncoder">
   <constructor-arg value="com.test.InMessageVo" />
```

```
  <bean id="emailvalueEncoder" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaEncoder">
   <constructor-arg value="com.test.EmailMessageVo" />
```

```
   <int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaInboundChannelAdapter"
        kafka-consumer-context-ref="consumerContext"
        auto-startup="false"
        channel="inputFromKafka">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1" time-unit="MILLISECONDS"/>
</int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>



 <int:channel id="inputFromKafka">
   <int:queue />
   </int:channel>


<int:channel id="receiveMessageFromKafka">
  <int:queue />
   </int:channel>



    <int-kafka:consumer-context id="consumerContext"
        consumer-timeout="1000"
        zookeeper-connect="zookeeperConnect" consumer-properties="consumerProperties">
    <int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:consumer-configuration group-id="default1"
                value-decoder="emailvalueDecoder"
                key-decoder="kafkaReflectionDecoder"
                max-messages="5000">
            <int-kafka:topic id="test1" streams="4"/>
        </int-kafka:consumer-configuration>

        <int-kafka:consumer-configuration group-id="default2"
                value-decoder="invalueDecoder"
                key-decoder="kafkaReflectionDecoder"
                max-messages="50">
        <int-kafka:topic id="test2" streams="4"/>
        </int-kafka:consumer-configuration>
    </int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
</int-kafka:consumer-context>


  <bean id="emailvalueDecoder" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroSpecificDatumBackedKafkaDecoder">
    <constructor-arg value="com.test.EmailMessageVo" />
</bean>


  <bean id="invalueDecoder" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroSpecificDatumBackedKafkaDecoder">
    <constructor-arg value="com.test.InMessageVo" />
</bean>
   <bean id="consumerService" class="com.test.ConsumerServiceHandler" />

   <int:service-activator id="advicedSa" input-channel="inputFromKafka" ref="consumerService"method="testConsumerCircuitBreaker" outputchannel="receiveMessageFromKafka">

   <int:channel id="inMessage_topic_channel">
   <int:queue />
```

```
   <int:channel id="emailMessage_topic_channel">
    <int:queue />
```

```
    <bean id="inMessageService" class="com.test.inMessageHandler" />

     <bean id="emailMessageService" class="com.test.emailMessageHandler" />

      <int:service-activator id="advicedSa1" input-channel="inMessage_topic_channel" ref="inMessageService"method="execute">

      <int:service-activator id="advicedSa2" input-channel="emailMessage_topic_channel" ref="emailMessageService"method="execute" >

       <int:router input-channel="receiveMessageFromKafka" expression="headers.topic">
       <int:mapping value="inMessage_topic" channel="inMessage_topic_channel"/>
       <int:mapping value="emailMessage_topic" channel="emailMessage_topic_channel"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should share with us what your `ConsumerServiceHandler` does. Just because your logic is a bit strange having the result from the `<int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>` as a `Message<Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Object>>>>` where it is a `Message<?> with the`payload` as *a map of topics and their messages by the partition sections*.

With the same `group-id` we (you?) end up with the issue that the last configuration wins overriding the previous:

```
consumerConfigurationsMap.put(consumerConfiguration.getAttribute("group-id"),
                consumerConfigurationBeanDefinition);
```

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan for your kind response

please find the consumerServiceHandler here : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d8cf04dcabd8e4463d33
 
ConsumerServiceHandler :remove topic/partition redundant details/setting the topic.

Message sent:  Message.withPayload(inMessageVO)/Message.withPayload(emailMessageVO),

and expecting same but getting in this format: Message<Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Object>>>>
 
overall intention :route different messages(inMessageVO/emailMessageVO) to diff handlers for processing
Please suggest, if it can be done in more better way.